# Is it possible to hide "Tab selection facility"?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to protect sheets with password.

So when user open the workbook I want that all sheets except one will be hidden( Very hidden). When user enter the password all sheets will be visible. How can I hide and show lot of sheets using vba code, is there any simple techniques? I mean is it possible to hide "Tab selection facility"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before, let me point out how Excel files are not secure:

1. Your code will be part of the file's XML, so inspecting the underlying data, anyone who wants to can find out how to get your password.

Now that you've been warned, here the code that you must include at the workbook open event. It will hide everything (to prevent scenarios where the sheets would have been left visible upon closing the book), then ask a password.

```
Public Sub UnlockSheets()
    ' 1 - hide every sheet, except the desired one
    Dim aWorksheet As Worksheet
    For Each aWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If aWorksheet.Name <> "desired sheet name" Then
            aWorksheet.Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Next

    ' 2 - ask for the password
    Dim userPassword As String
    userPassword = InputBox("Please enter your password")
    If userPassword = "my_password" Then
        RevealSheets
    Else
        MsgBox "Wrong password!", vbCritical
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub RevealSheets()
    '3 - Hide all the sheets
    Dim aWorksheet As Worksheet
    For Each aWorksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        aWorksheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next
End Sub
```

Another problem here is that the user can stop all macros by holding the SHIFT key (if I recall right). Needless to say... it's not too secure. Then again, Excel files aren't known for incredible safety.